# Everyday you make me cry

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Everyday you make me cry,
>
> You hit me to shut me up.
>
> Thankfully I'm not alive,
>
> But alas I've had enough.
>
> Finally, I've left you,
>
> But... you're not sad.
>
> because my replacement...
>
> Best friend you've ever had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re an

> Alarm Clock?

Everyday you make me cry,

> Every morning it “cries” to wake you up

You hit me to shut me up.

> You hit the off or snooze button

Thankfully I'm not alive,

> Alarm clocks aren’t

But alas I've had enough.

> They’re old and antiquated now

Finally, I've left you,

> Not many people have alarm clocks anymore

But... you're not sad.

> True

because my replacement...

> Generally, people use their phones for alarms now

Best friend you've ever had.

> People are always on their smartphones

Comment: Did I post it first or did you did it? ;-)

Comment: I beat you by 3 minutes it looks like haha — great answer @math !

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the answer:

> Alarm clock

Everyday you make me cry,

> Because we ourselves set the time to wake it up

You hit me to shut me up.

> Because we hit it to off it every time

Thankfully I'm not alive,

> A Clock is not alive

But alas I've had enough.

> Of course it had enough. Will you be an alarm clock ;-)

Finally, I've left you,

> We now use smart phones

But... you're not sad.

> Smart phones are easier to use

because my replacement...

> Smart phones

Best friend you've ever had.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

> You’re an alarm clock

Everyday you make me cry,

> We set the alarm so you cry (alarm goes off) in the morning

You hit me to shut me up.

> Snooze button

Thankfully I'm not alive,

> Alarm clocks are objects, obviously not living

But alas I've had enough.

> You broke

Finally, I've left you,

> We threw the broken alarm clock away

But... you're not sad.

> Amazon Alexa (or the like) are way simpler

because my replacement...

Best friend you've ever had.

> Amazon Alexa (and the like) make it easy to set an alarm or stop an alarm without even touching anything. You can also control the lights, etc. if you set it up correctly!